# Error in R Shiny: Input columns in `x` must be unique

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to deploy my Shiny app on `shinyapps.io`. My script runs well in local, but when I deployed it, I got this error message in the

> logs:
>  "Error: Input columns in `x` must be unique.
>  Problem
> with NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA".

I found there is a document mentions about this error [here](https://bookdown.org/khueniken/Merging_with_dplyr/advantages-of-dplyr-suite.html). It says the error occurs when your dataset has multiple columns with the same name, and the content follows `Problem with ...` in the error message as shown above is the name of the repeated columns. BUT I checked all my datasets and there is no column named `NA`, also I don't know where did the error occur and how to debug it since the error line was not displayed in logs
and I didn't get any error when I ran the code locally.

Does anyone have any idea or clue of how to solve this? Thanks!!

In case you need more information about the error, I am attaching a screenshot of the log here. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K6fI.png)

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Here, the first thing I'd do is look for references to resources on your local disk that won't be part of the deployment to shinyapps.io.

Comment: Hi Limey, thanks for your reply and suggestion! For the minimal reproducible example you suggested, actually I don't know how to provide it because I have long script and I don't know where the error occurred, I'm not sure which part of the code I need to use as an example.

Comment: That's exactly why we ask for a *minimal* reproducible example.  If *you* don't know where the error is, why should we trawl through your code to find it?

Comment: Hi Limey, I tried to create a minimal reproducible example so I followed the instruction in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you shared: _"If you’re not sure what the source of the problem is, start removing code a bit at a time until the problem disappears – then add the last part back."_ By doing this, I figured out the actual error in my code, [this post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/nas-are-not-allowed-in-subscripted-assignments/83272) can explain the error. Thanks for your inspiration and help!